# Find datacontext inside datatemplate

Tags: silverlight

I'm not a Silverlight expert and I'm struggling with an irritating problem.

I have a Telerik RadRichTextbox inside a Grid. This Grid is inside a DataTemplate which is part of an ItemsControl. Like so:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="_Editor" DocumentChanged="HandleditorDocumentChanged"/>
                <Xaml:XamlDataProvider x:Name="xamlProvider" Xaml="{Binding Text}" RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=_Editor}" />

                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text2}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the DocumentChanges event I want to access the DataContext of the DataTemplate. I tried setting the DataContext of the _Editor to {Binding} but in the code behind the DataContext is null.
I then thought of getting the parent of the _Editor, which is the Grid. Its DataContext is also null and the Grid its parent is also null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think what' you're looking for is a DataContext Proxy.  Consider this example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx